# how to install specific branch of git repository using yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I am able to install one GitHub package but not other using yarn. Please let me know what could be the issue here.

I can add https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox#3.0
but not https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux#result-post-processor

```
ravis-MacBook-Pro:gitprojects ******$ mkdir test
ravis-MacBook-Pro:gitprojects ******$ cd test
ravis-MacBook-Pro:test ***********$ yarn init
yarn init v1.6.0
question name (test): 
question version (1.0.0): 
question description: 
question entry point (index.js): 
question repository url: 
question author: 
question license (MIT): 
question private: 
success Saved package.json
✨  Done in 11.54s.

ravis-MacBook-Pro:test ******$ yarn add https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox#3.0
yarn add v1.6.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @fancyapps/fancybox@3.0.48" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=1.9.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @fancyapps/fancybox@3.0.48
info All dependencies
└─ @fancyapps/fancybox@3.0.48
✨  Done in 1.35s.


ravis-MacBook-Pro:test *******$ yarn add https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux#result-post-processor
yarn add v1.6.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Can't add "otp-react-redux": invalid package version undefined.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
ravis-MacBook-Pro:test *******$
```

Comment: I have a dilemma here.. both the answers are correct. If I don't have to modify the source, I have to use yarn 1.3.2 to install. I'm going to go with  botika's version because this means that I am using the correct version that the developer used to install the repo

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need use you git remote url and specify branch after hash(#).

```
yarn add https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux.git#result-post-processor
```

installs a package from a remote git repository at specific git branch, git commit or git tag.

`yarn add <git remote url>#<branch/commit/tag>`

[image]

Comment: I want the code from the specific branch result-post-processor

Comment: please use above command in answer. git remote url and specify branch after hash(#)

Comment: Please tell me if it's help you.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I'm using the exact command and it fails.  My original issue is also the same. You can see the error in my original post. Can you show the command from your machine

Comment: you are using https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux#result-post-processor that's wrong. use clone url

Comment: you need use remote url (with .git extension)

Comment: I will try this and let you know. I'm also planning to see if yarn version could be a problem

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**

Please note that for Yarn 2+ you need to prefix the URL with package name:

```
yarn add otp-react-redux@https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux#head=result-post-processor
```